# if include once success

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I got some trouble with if, elseif and else.

If the url is example.com include sites/home.php
Elseif the url is example.com/test include sites/$url.php
Else include sites/404.php

Here is my code:

```
            if ($url=='')

                include_once "sites/home.php";
            elseif (What to put here!!!? I need the elseif to happend if it is possible to include the $url file){
                include_once "sites/$url.php";

            }

            else {
                include_once 'sites/404.php';

            }
```

Hope you guys understand my question. I couldnt really expalin it in another way

Comment: i don't understand your question because you didn't actually ask a question..

Comment: What's the question? what's the problem? If this is actually your code you have an error with the brackets on the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($url=='') {
   include_once "sites/home.php";
} elseif (file_exists($url)) {
   include_once "sites/$url.php";
} else { 
   include_once 'sites/404.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do it.

```
if ($url=='') {
    include_once "sites/home.php";
}else if (file_exists("$url.php") && is_readable("$url.php")){
    include_once "sites/$url.php";
}else {
    include_once 'sites/404.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc (but not tested) :

```
"include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning"
```

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Then, your code would be:

```
        if ($url=='') {
             include_once "sites/home.php"
        }
        else {
              if (include_once sites/$url.php) {
                   // Do nothing : it worked !
              } 
              else {
                  include_once "sites/404.php";
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to use the `include` directive to find out whether a file exists. As per [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning.

Thus you'd need to:

- Suppress the warning with the `@` operator
- Compare against `false` with the `===` operator

It'll work but it'll be an awful hack. I suggest you rethink your logic so you know before hand what files are available to be included.

Answer (score -1):

You can test the file and if it exists and the script has the permissions to read it.

```
if ($url=='') {
      include_once "sites/home.php";
}
elseif (file_exists( $url . ".php") && is_readable($url . ".php")){  
        include_once "sites/" . $url . ".php";        
}
else {
      include_once 'sites/404.php';
}
```

Comment: You have an odd number of double quotes, `"`

Comment: Sorry about that, fixing right away
Edit: @mansuetus took care of it!